# opening a webpage in lightbox

Tags: javascript, lightbox

i am using [this](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) light box, please guide is it possiable to open the webpage instead of picture .

I have tried with the following approaches  but they didn't  worked

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="lightbox">Search google</a>

<a href="a.html" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/thumb-1.jpg" width="100" height="40" alt="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) Or Thickbox are better option if you want to use iFrame .

Comment: the problem with iframe is when i call another page which is continuously refreshing itself then its start blinking plus ajax support is not working with thickbox

Comment: Did you try FancyBox ? I myself am doing things related to ajax inside an iframe in fancybox and it absolutely works fine .

Comment: i have tried this in fancy frame <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#responsecontainer").load("user/leftm.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('user/leftm.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>

<div id="responsecontainer">
</div>

Comment: Can you try to refresh content on iframe itself instead of loading it and setting to a div outside of page ?

Comment: Thanks for your concern , please can you guide to any example

Comment: http://alex.mamchenkov.net/2010/05/21/jquery-fancybox-with-ajax/ instead of getJson you will call regular ajax method to get content.

Comment: @user608576 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1632/discussion-between-umar-and-user608576)